# SWFUpload IO Error on Vista

Tags: flash, uploadify, swfupload, ioerror

I have a problem. On my site everybody can fill the form and make an order. Also, people must upload a photo and an archive. I'm using a flash uploader for this.

Some people always get an `IO Error` and I can't understand why. On Windows XP and Windows 7 I have no problems. On Vista and error occures sometimes, but not always.

- I've tried to use SWFUpload 2.2.0, SWFUpload 2.5.0 and Uploadify 2.1.4. There is no difference.
- I've Tested in Firefox, Chrome and IE. This error can happen everywhere. With any size of file.
- There is no `IO Error` in Apache's log after the error occurs.
- `mod_security` is off. There is not http authentication. No SSL. Not file size limit.
- The problem is not with AntiVirus.

My app uses Python, Flask. Of course I've tried to find a solution using Google, this site and the flash uploader forums. Nothing helped.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Increase Apache's Timeout. See if that helps.

I have the same issue with flash on linux. Never seen it on vista. Used 2.2.0

I know you mentioned no ssl but I think its worth mentioning for other people's benefit that flash has issues with non valid certificates and will cause i/o error.

To debug further, you might want to use fiddler and/or wireshark.